# Lorentz transformation of basis vectors in The geometry of Minkowski spacetime by Gregory L. Naber

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, vectors

Gregory L. Naber's book introduces the Lorentz transformation like this:

> Now let $L :M→M$ be an orthogonal transformation of $M$ and
> ${e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4}$ an orthonormal basis for M. By Lemma 1.2.3, $\hat{e}_1 = Le_1$, $\hat{e}_2 = Le_2$, $\hat{e}_3 = Le_3$ and $\hat{e}_4 = Le_4$ also form an orthonormal basis for $M$. In particular, each $e_u$, $u = $1, 2, 3, 4, can be expressed as a linear combination of the $\hat{e}_a$: $$e_u = {\Lambda^1}_u\hat{e}_1 + {\Lambda^2}_u\hat{e}_2 + {\Lambda^3}_u\hat{e}_3 + {\Lambda^4}_u\hat{e}_4$$ $$u = 1, 2, 3, 4$$

I think this is a mistake, it should be like this (so the new basis can be constracted from the old, not the other way):

$$\hat{e}_u = {\Lambda^1}_u{e}_1 + {\Lambda^2}_u{e}_2 + {\Lambda^3}_u{e}_3 + {\Lambda^4}_u{e}_4$$

Or if the original is the the good one, I do not understand, where it came from.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a mistake. We would not want to write $$\hat e_u=\Lambda^1{}_u e_1 +\Lambda^2{}_u e_2 +\Lambda^3{}_u e_3 +\Lambda^4{}_u e_4$$ because we already are already given that $$\hat e_u = Le_u$$ So there is no point in writing it in that first way. The author is attempting to show the form and characteristics of the inverse transform, given the knowledge that the forward transform is orthogonal.

Regarding where the original basis came from, it was simply given.

Comment: Sorry, there was not enough context. The author writes later: "Observe, that $\Lambda$ is actually the matrix of $L^{-1}$ relative to the basis {$\hat{e}_a$}". Then: "We regard the matrix $\Lambda$ associated with $L$ and {$e_a$} as a coordinate transformation matrix in the usual way." and an example: $$\hat{x}_1 = {\Lambda^1}_1x^1 + {\Lambda^1}_2x^2 + {\Lambda^1}_3x^3 + {\Lambda^1}_4x^4.$$

For me, it looks like first $\Lambda$ represents the inverse of $L$ then it represents $L$ itself. Or am I wrong?